# How do I publish a service on the API Store?

Tags: api, wsdl, registry, wso2, wso2-api-manager

First I downloaded below zip files,

- WSO2 API Manager 1.2.0 and
- WSO2 Governance Registry 4.5.2.

My goal was to

1. to create a Service based on a WSDL and a number of XSDs and then
2. to publish this Service on the pretty API Store user interface.

First off I created a Service by importing a WSDL in "API Manager" using the "Managment Console" (`https://localhost:9443/carbon/admin/index.jsp?loginStatus=true`). Then I didn't find any straight-forward way to publish that one as an API, because I didn't find a way attaching a life-cycle to the Service as described in [product documentation "Publish Service as API"](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance452/API+Manager).

How should I do? Do I need to configure the "API Manager" to use the database of "Governance Registry" as discussed on [this article](http://wso2.org/library/tutorials/2010/04/sharing-registry-space-across-multiple-product-instances) or is there an easier way?

I am just playing around prototyping so I appreciate if there are easy solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find how to attach a life-cycle to a created service in G-Reg from [here](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance452/Managing+Services#ManagingServices-ServiceVersioning). After following it once you promote the service until it gets to the production state, then you can publish that service as an API. And then you can see your created API from api-publisher app.

However note that when you are trying to change the created API status as 'published' from publisher-app, as explained in your mentioned [documentation](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance452/API+Manager), it contains the known bug as [APIMANAGER-834](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-834). We are currently working on a fix for this issue.

Comment: Reading about APIMANAGER-834 I realize I do need to attach the life-cycle in the "Governance Registry 4.5.2" product and then connect the "API Manager 1.2.0" product to the db of "Governance Registry 4.5.2". Trying to do all steps in only "API Manager 1.2.0" does not seem to be possible. Am I right?

Comment: Yes,You need to use both GREG 4.5.2 and AM 1.2.0.

Comment: Following the link to the bug above I see it is planned to be included in API Manager 1.3.0 which is due friday this week.